# SwaggerUI - custom URL base path

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, base-url

I am using SwaggerUI to document the REST API of an application written in Java. Unfortunately the "Try it out" feature does not work because the generated URLs are missing a part of the path.

The setup:

```
<myHost:port>/myApplication/swagger-ui <-- web fronted of the Swagger UI
<myHost:port>/myApplication/rest/<customRestCall> <-- base URL of the documented REST API
```

The documentation is generated using Swagger version 3, namely `io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.OpenApiResource` as downloaded by Gradle from mvnrepository:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.codegen.v3/swagger-codegen-generators
implementation group: 'io.swagger.codegen.v3', name: 'swagger-codegen-generators', version: '1.0.+'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-jaxrs2
implementation group:'io.swagger.core.v3', name:'swagger-jaxrs2', version:'2.0.+'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer
implementation group:'io.swagger.core.v3', name:'swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer', version:'2.0.+'
```

Currently Swaggers try-out-feature calls URL following `<myHost:port>/<customRestCall>`.
How can the documentation generation in Java ( rsulting in myApplication.war ) be configured to generate / call `<myHost:port>/myApplication/rest/<customRestCall>` instead? (`<myHost:port>` should not be fixed path of the configuration as there are different hosts for testing / integration / production )

Thank you for your support!

Comment: try setting `server:context-path: "/myApplication/rest/"` in bootstrap.yml file. this will change the context path for all the API in controller

Comment: @Swaraj do I just need to add this bootstrap.yml to my ressource and config files to have the API documentation generator find it?

Comment: resources folder if bootstrap.yml is not there then create new.

Comment: @Swaraj I tried several locations to place the bootstrap.yml in my application including the Java resources folder, META-INF, WEB-INF, web-root-folder, but none worked. Also using a custom class derived from `OpenApiResource` and calling `setConfigLocation` before generating the documentation did not help.

Any futher instructions or ideas on this are welcome.